# Biblatex not working (Linux Mint)

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use the biblatex package, but when I compile my file it simply doesn't print any bibliography.

This is the file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Master.bib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,heightrounded}
\begin{document}
...
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'm using Texmaker on Linux Mint.

Comment: Wewlcome to tex.sx.  This question might be of some help: [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)  The main thing that's important when using any bibliography package is the need to process the bibliography separately after the first LaTeX run, and then run LaTeX again after the bibliography processing is completed without errors.

Comment: You need to run Biber on your file so that your compilation sequence is LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX can be any flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a great explanation why that is necessary and what Biber does. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run TeX for you.

Comment: how can I run Biber? Sorry, I'm a newbie :)

Comment: If you use your editor to compile your document, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to compile your document? If not, can you please explain what you tried so far and how it did not work for you?